# How do I use mysqli in an included file when the mysqli connection is stored in another included file?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm about to use mysqli instead of mysql for the first time in my procedural PHP application.

**index.php**

```
include(db_conn.php);

<html>
<body>
    <?php include(content.php);?>
</body>
</html
```

**db_conn.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

**content.php**

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
# more code...
```

mysqli_query necessarily requires the connection variable and my connection is stored in variable ***$con*** in the included **db_conn.php** file which is unavailable in another included **content.php** file.

Comment: I think this is working. Any errors ??

Comment: For the setup provided it's perfectly available. So you oversimplified yoir example.making it impossible to point out at yet another silly error

Comment: or **add `include(db_conn.php);` in `content.php`**

Comment: are the filepaths correct? The way you wrote it all files would be in the same folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Within your content.php use require(db_conn.php); And if you have a function defined in there, you're going to have to put require(db_conn.php); INSIDE that function.

The database connection doesn't seem to have exactly the same scoping as a standard variable.

I know when coding it, you feel like "I should only have to include this once!" but *shrug* get everything else working first, and if someone wants to pay you to go back and try to "fix" this... work on it then. ;)